# python: parsing certain values from svg file

Tags: python, xml, svg, nodes

I have a svg file like the following (en example)

```
<svg 
<g class="displacy-arrow">
<path class="displacy-arc" id="arrow-ec55d4518d3c43e391ffce0b97c713ab-0-2" stroke-width="2px" d="M420,89.5 C420,2.0 575.0,2.0 575.0,89.5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"/>
<text dy="1.25em" style="font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 1px">
    <textPath xlink:href="#arrow-ec55d4518d3c43e391ffce0b97c713ab-0-2" class="displacy-label" startOffset="50%" side="left" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle">pd</textPath>
</text>
<path class="displacy-arrowhead" d="M575.0,91.5 L583.0,79.5 567.0,79.5" fill="currentColor"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I have tried to access the what is inside the 'textpath' node using the code below:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('my_file.svg')
name = doc.getElementsByTagName('textPath')
for t in name:
    print([x.nodeValue for x in t.childNodes])
```

I would however like to get the other information included in the 'textpath', like the values for 'side' or 'fill', but I do not know how to access those.

Comment: Libraries like html parser (https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html ), beautiful soup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ come handy for these parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for future reference, I wrote a function based on the links that @Aswath has sent in the comments

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_data_from_report3(filename):
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "html.parser")
for element in soup.find_all('textpath'):
    print(element.get('side'))
```

extract_data_from_report3('my_file.svg')